# How does one scrape data from Google maps API over overlay?

Tags: google-maps, web-scraping

I have been unable to find a method for this. I want to scrape the following two websites:

- http://www.ugebreveta4.dk/i-disse-postnumre-bor-der-snart-flere-indvandrere-end_19954.aspx
- http://www.dr.dk/nyheder/politik/valg2015/kort-saa-meget-tjener-folk-i-dit-nabolag

The first is a map of all Danish ZIP codes and the proportion of (recent) immigrants in each. Additionally, there is country area if one clicks on the areas.

The second is a comprehensive map of socioeconomic information such as age, income and voting outcome for each Danish voting district. There looks to be several hundred. One can click the entries, but there is no effect. But there is a onmouseover effect which may be useful.

**Examining requests**
The first thing I did was examine the requests sent by my browser as I open the page. I use Firefox's built in F12 menu for this purpose. This analysis shows that there is no useful .json file being transferred, which would be easy to scrape. Instead, both sites send the image files (.png) of which the map is made of, with and without overlay.

This opens for one way of getting the data, namely by downloading all these images in a high resolution (i.e. zoom-level) and then putting them back together with an algorithm. Algorithms for this kind of problem exist and are used e.g. in [genomics](https://plus.maths.org/content/os/issue55/features/sequencing/index).

**Site 1**
When one clicks one of the areas, a pop-up pops up. When this happens, the browser sends a request to fetch it, e.g. (Skagen, the northmost part of Jutland, ZIP = 9990 [[list here]](http://www.postnumre.dk/)):

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/LayersService.GetFeature?1sft%3A1uHHijeWypO-5FlUoVWEbyBcQY8AoM4mHVIqOo182&2s33%3A4611686018427392936%232492_5032_40_592_732_329&3sen-US&4m2&1ssg&2s&4m2&1ssc&2sgeometry&4m2&1sy&2s2&callback=_xdc_._1ju85&token=51906
```

The response is a code file with some data. For the one above:

```
/**/_xdc_._1ju85 && _xdc_._1ju85( [0,[0,0],[["maps_api.col0\u003e\u003e0.Postnummer","9990"],["maps_api.col1\u003e\u003e0.Danmark","7800"],["maps_api.col2\u003e\u003e0.Nordeuropa (uden DK)","99"],["maps_api.col3\u003e\u003e0.Vesteuropa","36"],["maps_api.col4\u003e\u003e0.Østeuropa","275"],["maps_api.col5\u003e\u003e0.Sydeuropa","13"],["maps_api.col6\u003e\u003e0.Nordamerika","4"],["maps_api.col7\u003e\u003e0.Syd- og Mellemamerika","0"],["maps_api.col8\u003e\u003e0.Asien","75"],["maps_api.col9\u003e\u003e0.Afrika","29"],["maps_api.col10\u003e\u003e0.Australien/New Zealand","0"],["maps_api.col11\u003e\u003e0.I alt","8351"],["maps_api.col12\u003e\u003e0.Land2","Rumænien"],["maps_api.col13\u003e\u003e0.Indbyggere 2","205"],["maps_api.col14\u003e\u003e0.Land3","Polen"],["maps_api.col15\u003e\u003e0.Indbyggere3","44"],["maps_api.col16\u003e\u003e0.Land4","Sverige"],["maps_api.col17\u003e\u003e0.Indbyggere4","34"],["maps_api.col18\u003e\u003e0.Land5","Tyskland"],["maps_api.col19\u003e\u003e0.Indbyggere5","26"],["maps_api.col20\u003e\u003e0.Land6","Norge"],["maps_api.col21\u003e\u003e0.Indbyggere6","24"],["maps_api.col22\u003e\u003e0.Land7","Thailand"],["maps_api.col23\u003e\u003e0.Indbyggere7","23"],["maps_api.col24\u003e\u003e0.Land8","Syrien"],["maps_api.col25\u003e\u003e0.Indbyggere8","20"],["maps_api.col26\u003e\u003e0.Land9","Storbritannien"],["maps_api.col27\u003e\u003e0.Indbyggere9","18"],["maps_api.col28\u003e\u003e0.Land10","Sudan"],["maps_api.col29\u003e\u003e0.Indbyggere10","17"],["maps_api.col30\u003e\u003e0.Land11","Litauen"],["maps_api.col31\u003e\u003e0.Indbyggere11","13"],["maps_api.col1\u003e\u003e1.geometry_vertex_count","60"],["maps_api.col2\u003e\u003e1.UUID","til fremtidig brug"],["maps_api.col11\u003e\u003e1.POSTBYNAVN","Skagen"],["maps_api.col5\u003e\u003e2.BYNAVN","Skagen"],["maps_api.col1\u003e\u003e3.1 Dansk","7800"],["maps_api.col2\u003e\u003e3.2 Indvandrere","500"],["maps_api.col3\u003e\u003e3.3 Efterkommere","51"],["maps_api.col4\u003e\u003e3.Dansk andel","93%"],["maps_api.col5\u003e\u003e3.Indvandrere andel","6%"],["maps_api.col6\u003e\u003e3.Efterkommere andel","1%"],["maps_api.col7\u003e\u003e3.procent","7%"],["maps_api.col1\u003e\u003e4.Farveland","4"],["maps_api.col1\u003e\u003e5.FARVE","44"],["description","\u003cdiv class=\"googft-info-window\"\u003e\n\u003cb\u003ePostnummer:\u003c/b\u003e 9990\u003cbr\u003e\n\u003cb\u003eDanmark:\u003c/b\u003e 7800\u003cbr\u003e\n\u003cb\u003eNordeuropa (uden DK):\u003c/b\u003e 99\u003cbr\u003e\n\u003cb\u003eVesteuropa:\u003c/b\u003e 36\u003cbr\u003e\n\u003cb\u003eØsteuropa:\u003c/b\u003e 275\u003cbr\u003e\n\u003cb\u003eSydeuropa:\u003c/b\u003e 13\u003cbr\u003e\n\u003cb\u003eNordamerika:\u003c/b\u003e 4\u003cbr\u003e\n\u003cb\u003eSyd- og Mellemamerika:\u003c/b\u003e 0\u003cbr\u003e\n\u003cb\u003eAsien:\u003c/b\u003e 75\u003cbr\u003e\n\u003cb\u003eAfrika:\u003c/b\u003e 29\n\u003c/div\u003e"]]] )
```

It has a lot of Unicode, removing this we get:

```
/**/_xdc_._1ju85 && _xdc_._1ju85( [0,[0,0],[["maps_api.col0\>\>0.Postnummer","9990"],["maps_api.col1\>\>0.Danmark","7800"],["maps_api.col2\>\>0.Nordeuropa (uden DK)","99"],["maps_api.col3\>\>0.Vesteuropa","36"],["maps_api.col4\>\>0.Østeuropa","275"],["maps_api.col5\>\>0.Sydeuropa","13"],["maps_api.col6\>\>0.Nordamerika","4"],["maps_api.col7\>\>0.Syd- og Mellemamerika","0"],["maps_api.col8\>\>0.Asien","75"],["maps_api.col9\>\>0.Afrika","29"],["maps_api.col10\>\>0.Australien/New Zealand","0"],["maps_api.col11\>\>0.I alt","8351"],["maps_api.col12\>\>0.Land2","Rumænien"],["maps_api.col13\>\>0.Indbyggere 2","205"],["maps_api.col14\>\>0.Land3","Polen"],["maps_api.col15\>\>0.Indbyggere3","44"],["maps_api.col16\>\>0.Land4","Sverige"],["maps_api.col17\>\>0.Indbyggere4","34"],["maps_api.col18\>\>0.Land5","Tyskland"],["maps_api.col19\>\>0.Indbyggere5","26"],["maps_api.col20\>\>0.Land6","Norge"],["maps_api.col21\>\>0.Indbyggere6","24"],["maps_api.col22\>\>0.Land7","Thailand"],["maps_api.col23\>\>0.Indbyggere7","23"],["maps_api.col24\>\>0.Land8","Syrien"],["maps_api.col25\>\>0.Indbyggere8","20"],["maps_api.col26\>\>0.Land9","Storbritannien"],["maps_api.col27\>\>0.Indbyggere9","18"],["maps_api.col28\>\>0.Land10","Sudan"],["maps_api.col29\>\>0.Indbyggere10","17"],["maps_api.col30\>\>0.Land11","Litauen"],["maps_api.col31\>\>0.Indbyggere11","13"],["maps_api.col1\>\>1.geometry_vertex_count","60"],["maps_api.col2\>\>1.UUID","til fremtidig brug"],["maps_api.col11\>\>1.POSTBYNAVN","Skagen"],["maps_api.col5\>\>2.BYNAVN","Skagen"],["maps_api.col1\>\>3.1 Dansk","7800"],["maps_api.col2\>\>3.2 Indvandrere","500"],["maps_api.col3\>\>3.3 Efterkommere","51"],["maps_api.col4\>\>3.Dansk andel","93%"],["maps_api.col5\>\>3.Indvandrere andel","6%"],["maps_api.col6\>\>3.Efterkommere andel","1%"],["maps_api.col7\>\>3.procent","7%"],["maps_api.col1\>\>4.Farveland","4"],["maps_api.col1\>\>5.FARVE","44"],["description","\<div class=\"googft-info-window\"\>\n\<b\>Postnummer:\</b\> 9990\<br\>\n\<b\>Danmark:\</b\> 7800\<br\>\n\<b\>Nordeuropa (uden DK):\</b\> 99\<br\>\n\<b\>Vesteuropa:\</b\> 36\<br\>\n\<b\>Østeuropa:\</b\> 275\<br\>\n\<b\>Sydeuropa:\</b\> 13\<br\>\n\<b\>Nordamerika:\</b\> 4\<br\>\n\<b\>Syd- og Mellemamerika:\</b\> 0\<br\>\n\<b\>Asien:\</b\> 75\<br\>\n\<b\>Afrika:\</b\> 29\n\</div\>"]]] )
```

This response actually lists the number of immigrants at the country level, not just the country area (e.g. Asia) as the map does. E.g. we can see that there are 205 from Rumænien (Romania). One could parse this with regex to get the numbers. This would not be too difficult or time consuming.

However, the problem is that the parameter values of the request are not predictable from the map or ZIP codes as far as I can tell. Here is another request for the region right below it (Ålbæk; ZIP 9982):

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/LayersService.GetFeature?1sft:1uHHijeWypO-5FlUoVWEbyBcQY8AoM4mHVIqOo182&2s33:4611686018427393993#2491_6089_1017_591_731_733&3sen-US&4m2&1ssg&2s&4m2&1ssc&2sgeometry&4m2&1sy&2s2&callback=_xdc_._x7sxj1&token=128412
```

There are a host of numbers that do not seem be to related to the area or the zip code or anything else I can think of. My guess is that they are some kind of hash of the the relevant information.

I note that since there is an onmouseover event for each area and that this sends the request, if one could somehow get the information embedded in this object, one would perhaps be able to find all the requests and then use a script to fetch all the data. I don't know if one can somehow inspect the object to see all the related events.

**Site 2**
There is no pop-up for this site, so one cannot use the above approach. However, examining the image requests opens another strategy. For instance:

```
https://mts1.googleapis.com/mapslt?hl=en-US&lyrs=ft%3A1Z6wK9yVyZ5nXmHTDOQs5zAfSdcKeMSMoJGswIIDW%7Cc%3Ag%3Affffcc%3Bp%3AB3%3Bt%3A444444%24g%3Ac2e699%3Bp%3AB3%3Bt%3A444444%24g%3A78c679%3Bp%3AB3%3Bt%3A444444%24g%3A31a354%3Bp%3AB3%3Bt%3A444444%24g%3A006837%3Bp%3AB3%3Bt%3A444444%7Csc%3Acol9%253E%253E0%7Csg%3A%7Csq%3A%27Andel%2520offentlig%2520fors%25C3%25B8rgelse%2520I%2520ALT%2520antal%27%2520%253E%2520-0.000001%2520AND%2520%27Andel%2520offentlig%2520fors%25C3%25B8rgelse%2520I%2520ALT%2520antal%27%2520%253C%253D%25200.1%24%27Andel%2520offentlig%2520fors%25C3%25B8rgelse%2520I%2520ALT%2520antal%27%2520%253E%25200.099999%2520AND%2520%27Andel%2520offentlig%2520fors%25C3%25B8rgelse%2520I%2520ALT%2520antal%27%2520%253C%253D%25200.2%24%27Andel%2520offentlig%2520fors%25C3%25B8rgelse%2520I%2520ALT%2520antal%27%2520%253E%25200.199999%2520AND%2520%27Andel%2520offentlig%2520fors%25C3%25B8rgelse%2520I%2520ALT%2520antal%27%2520%253C%253D%25200.30000000000000004%24%27Andel%2520offentlig%2520fors%25C3%25B8rgelse%2520I%2520ALT%2520antal%27%2520%253E%25200.29999900000000007%2520AND%2520%27Andel%2520offentlig%2520fors%25C3%25B8rgelse%2520I%2520ALT%2520antal%27%2520%253C%253D%25200.4%24%27Andel%2520offentlig%2520fors%25C3%25B8rgelse%2520I%2520ALT%2520antal%27%2520%253E%25200.39999900000000005%2520AND%2520%27Andel%2520offentlig%2520fors%25C3%25B8rgelse%2520I%2520ALT%2520antal%27%2520%253C%253D%25200.5%7Ctmplt%3A2%7Cy%3A2&x=1095&y=640&z=11&w=256&h=256&source=apiv3&token=39871
```

This shows part of Copenhagen (the capital) and is color coded for fraction of the population receiving welfare benefits ("offentlig forsørgelse"). The URL request is monstrous, but it is HTML encoded and decoding it gives this result:

```
https://mts1.googleapis.com/mapslt?hl=en-US&lyrs=ft:1Z6wK9yVyZ5nXmHTDOQs5zAfSdcKeMSMoJGswIIDW|c:g:ffffcc;p:B3;t:444444$g:c2e699;p:B3;t:444444$g:78c679;p:B3;t:444444$g:31a354;p:B3;t:444444$g:006837;p:B3;t:444444|sc:col9%3E%3E0|sg:|sq:'Andel%20offentlig%20fors%C3%B8rgelse%20I%20ALT%20antal'%20%3E%20-0.000001%20AND%20'Andel%20offentlig%20fors%C3%B8rgelse%20I%20ALT%20antal'%20%3C%3D%200.1$'Andel%20offentlig%20fors%C3%B8rgelse%20I%20ALT%20antal'%20%3E%200.099999%20AND%20'Andel%20offentlig%20fors%C3%B8rgelse%20I%20ALT%20antal'%20%3C%3D%200.2$'Andel%20offentlig%20fors%C3%B8rgelse%20I%20ALT%20antal'%20%3E%200.199999%20AND%20'Andel%20offentlig%20fors%C3%B8rgelse%20I%20ALT%20antal'%20%3C%3D%200.30000000000000004$'Andel%20offentlig%20fors%C3%B8rgelse%20I%20ALT%20antal'%20%3E%200.29999900000000007%20AND%20'Andel%20offentlig%20fors%C3%B8rgelse%20I%20ALT%20antal'%20%3C%3D%200.4$'Andel%20offentlig%20fors%C3%B8rgelse%20I%20ALT%20antal'%20%3E%200.39999900000000005%20AND%20'Andel%20offentlig%20fors%C3%B8rgelse%20I%20ALT%20antal'%20%3C%3D%200.5|tmplt:2|y:2&x=1095&y=640&z=11&w=256&h=256&source=apiv3&token=39871
```

There is still some encoding left, so we decode it again:

```
https://mts1.googleapis.com/mapslt?hl=en-US&lyrs=ft:1Z6wK9yVyZ5nXmHTDOQs5zAfSdcKeMSMoJGswIIDW|c:g:ffffcc;p:B3;t:444444$g:c2e699;p:B3;t:444444$g:78c679;p:B3;t:444444$g:31a354;p:B3;t:444444$g:006837;p:B3;t:444444|sc:col9>>0|sg:|sq:'Andel offentlig forsørgelse I ALT antal' > -0.000001 AND 'Andel offentlig forsørgelse I ALT antal' <= 0.1$'Andel offentlig forsørgelse I ALT antal' > 0.099999 AND 'Andel offentlig forsørgelse I ALT antal' <= 0.2$'Andel offentlig forsørgelse I ALT antal' > 0.199999 AND 'Andel offentlig forsørgelse I ALT antal' <= 0.30000000000000004$'Andel offentlig forsørgelse I ALT antal' > 0.29999900000000007 AND 'Andel offentlig forsørgelse I ALT antal' <= 0.4$'Andel offentlig forsørgelse I ALT antal' > 0.39999900000000005 AND 'Andel offentlig forsørgelse I ALT antal' <= 0.5|tmplt:2|y:2&x=1095&y=640&z=11&w=256&h=256&source=apiv3&token=39871
```

Now we see the request structure fairly clearly. It has the parameters for deciding the colored regions. We can modify these as we like to obtain more numbers. For instance:

```
https://mts1.googleapis.com/mapslt?hl=en-US&lyrs=ft%3A1Z6wK9yVyZ5nXmHTDOQs5zAfSdcKeMSMoJGswIIDW%7Cc%3Ag%3Affffcc%3Bp%3AB3%3Bt%3A444444%24g%3Ac2e699%3Bp%3AB3%3Bt%3A444444%24g%3A78c679%3Bp%3AB3%3Bt%3A444444%24g%3A31a354%3Bp%3AB3%3Bt%3A444444%24g%3A006837%3Bp%3AB3%3Bt%3A444444%7Csc%3Acol9%253E%253E0%7Csg%3A%7Csq%3A%27Andel%2520offentlig%2520fors%25C3%25B8rgelse%2520I%2520ALT%2520antal%27%2520%253E%2520.0%2520AND%2520%27Andel%2520offentlig%2520fors%25C3%25B8rgelse%2520I%2520ALT%2520antal%27%2520%253C%253D%25200.2%24%27Andel%2520offentlig%2520fors%25C3%25B8rgelse%2520I%2520ALT%2520antal%27%2520%253E%252000.2001%2520AND%2520%27Andel%2520offentlig%2520fors%25C3%25B8rgelse%2520I%2520ALT%2520antal%27%2520%253C%253D%25200.9%24%27Andel%2520offentlig%2520fors%25C3%25B8rgelse%2520I%2520ALT%2520antal%27%2520%253E%25209.9%2520AND%2520%27Andel%2520offentlig%2520fors%25C3%25B8rgelse%2520I%2520ALT%2520antal%27%2520%253C%253D%25209.9%24%27Andel%2520offentlig%2520fors%25C3%25B8rgelse%2520I%2520ALT%2520antal%27%2520%253E%25209.9%2520AND%2520%27Andel%2520offentlig%2520fors%25C3%25B8rgelse%2520I%2520ALT%2520antal%27%2520%253C%253D%25209.9%24%27Andel%2520offentlig%2520fors%25C3%25B8rgelse%2520I%2520ALT%2520antal%27%2520%253E%25209.9%2520AND%2520%27Andel%2520offentlig%2520fors%25C3%25B8rgelse%2520I%2520ALT%2520antal%27%2520%253C%253D%25209.9%7Ctmplt%3A2%7Cy%3A2&x=1095&y=640&z=11&w=256&h=256&source=apiv3&token=39871
```

Here I have changed the first interval to 0.0 to 0.2, the second to 0.2001 to 0.9 and the rest to 9.9 to 9.9 (i.e. impossible as largest possible value is 1). This redraws the map with only those two distinctions. One can then use a script to systematically vary these parameters to get precise numbers for each area.

**How to proceed from here?**
This is where I'm stuck and have been for some time. I don't know how to proceed from here. Any help is appreciated.

I am interesting in the numbers out of personal curiosity and for future sociological research.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The datasources of both Maps are FusionTables:

- **www.ugebreveta4.dk:** https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1uHHijeWypO-5FlUoVWEbyBcQY8AoM4mHVIqOo182#map:id=5
- **www.dr.dk:** https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1Z6wK9yVyZ5nXmHTDOQs5zAfSdcKeMSMoJGswIIDW#map:id=3

Both FusionTables are downloadable

Comment: here: [Fusion Tables Rest API](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v2/reference/) and [FusionTablesLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/fusiontableslayer) (that's what they use in their maps)

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the link you pasted the ft: is the fusion table id

```
https://mts1.googleapis.com/mapslt?hl=en-US&lyrs=ft:1Z6wK9yVyZ5nXmHTDOQs5zAfSdcKeMSMoJGswIIDW|
```

Using the Id **1Z6wK9yVyZ5nXmHTDOQs5zAfSdcKeMSMoJGswIIDW** you can get the full document using the url that **Dr.Molle** pasted using the table id in the docid paramter

https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1uHHijeWypO-5FlUoVWEbyBcQY8AoM4mHVIqOo182

You can alsoget the information using querys like this
encodeURIComponent("SELECT * FROM 1Z6wK9yVyZ5nXmHTDOQs5zAfSdcKeMSMoJGswIIDW")

and then use the encodded uri in this url
http://www.google.com/fusiontables/gvizdata?tq=SELECT%20*%20FROM%201Z6wK9yVyZ5nXmHTDOQs5zAfSdcKeMSMoJGswIIDW

more info in https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/fusiontables